# Facebook Graph API: Find graph object from post URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2, indieweb

Given the URL of a public Facebook post, how can one find the post object in the FB Graph API? (secondarily, why are so many user feeds empty or nearly empty when accessed through the API?)

We would like to be able to [comment on](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments) or [like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/likes) a post via the v2.x
Graph API, given the post's URL. Doing so requires the post's object
ID, which we can make some educated guesses about, but accessing
the actual object through the API has proven unreliable (works for some posts but
not others).

v2 of the API introduced [app-scoped user IDs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids), and post IDs generally seem
to be of the form {app-scoped user id}_{unique post id}. Here are the
details of some attempts to find posts in the API with various combinations of
these IDs (global user id, app-scoped user id, and post id).

- Starting with a simple example: https://www.facebook.com/evan.prodromou/posts/10153023417510505. Key characteristics are that it's public, it's not a share of another post, and most importantly it has no photo(s), which add extra ids and URLs for the individual photo(s) and photo set. Evan's profile is also public, i.e. https://www.facebook.com/evan.prodromou doesn't show the generic This content is currently unavailable
- Trying the bare post id from that URL, [/v1.0/10153023417510505](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v1.0/10153023417510505&version=unversioned&) and [/v2.2/10153023417510505](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v2.2/10153023417510505&version=unversioned&) both give the *Unsupported get request* (code 100) error.
- Evan's global user id is 525575504. Attaching that as a prefix, [/v1.0/525575504_10153023417510505](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v1.0/525575504_10153023417510505&version=unversioned&) and [/v2.2/525575504_10153023417510505](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v2.2/525575504_10153023417510505&version=unversioned&) still both give the same *Unsupported get request* error.
- Same error using his app-scoped user id instead, [/v2.2/10152350676805505_10153023417510505](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v2.2/10152350676805505_10153023417510505&version=unversioned&).

OK let's try the other direction. We'll page through the user's feed until we find the post in question. It feels like this is more the *expected* use case for the API...

- Both the global [/v2.2/525575504/posts](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v2.2/525575504/posts&version=unversioned&) and app-scoped [/v2.2/10152350676805505/posts](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=10152350676805505%2Fposts&version=v2.2&) return nothing, but [/v1.0/525575504/posts](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v1.0/525575504/posts&version=unversioned&) returns two recent posts, [this like](https://www.facebook.com/evan.prodromou/posts/10153045879215505) and [this post](https://www.facebook.com/525575504/posts/351575675029953). Not sure why only those two, even though has plenty of other recent public posts. The like is fetchable via its `id` field in both api versions, i.e. [/v1.0/525575504_10153045879215505](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v1.0/525575504_10153045879215505&version=unversioned&) and [/v2.2/10152350676805505_10153045879215505](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v2.2/10152350676805505_10153045879215505&version=unversioned&), but both API versions return the *Unsupported get request* error when fetching the post via its id field, e.g. [/v1.0/525575504_351575675029953](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v1.0/525575504_351575675029953&version=unversioned&) and [/v2.2/10152350676805505_351575675029953](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v2.2/10152350676805505_351575675029953&version=unversioned&)
- Trying another public post, this one with pictures: https://www.facebook.com/andigalpern/posts/678121182314631 . [/v1.0/100003502653187_678121182314631](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v1.0/100003502653187_678121182314631&version=unversioned&), [/v2.2/100003502653187_678121182314631](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v2.2/100003502653187_678121182314631&version=unversioned&), and [/v2.2/499657186827699_678121182314631](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v2.2/499657186827699_678121182314631&version=unversioned&) all error.
- [/v1.0/100003502653187/posts](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v1.0/100003502653187/posts&version=unversioned&) only includes one post, a like, and [/v2.2/100003502653187/posts](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=v2.2/100003502653187/posts&version=unversioned&) is empty.

For reference, here is [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/snarfed/bridgy/issues/350) where we have been tracking this problem.

Comment: Correct is that with API v2, there is no `username` field any more, and your app will not be allowed to use the global user id to request user details any more either, only the app-scoped user id. What I am wondering here, is why is there a need to request post details based on a post _URL_ in the first place? Normally your app should work with data that it requested via API before already, so “external” URLs like this would not come into play in the first place.

Comment: The goal is for someone to post a reply to or like of a FB status on their own personal website, and then use an app to publish it to Facebook. More details here: https://www.brid.gy/about#publishing.

Comment: try my answer maybe it will put you in right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you would need `read_stream` for this (which your app will not get granted). And yes, even though the post is public, you still need `read_stream` to be able to get read access to all kinds of posts.

You can easily play around with this in Graph API Explorer. First give your app `read_stream` permission to get ids of items in your feed – that will give you ids of the “form app-scoped user id underscore post id”. Then remove `read_stream` (by clicking “Get Access Token” again and using the “Clear” button), and try several of the `user_*` permissions – and you will see that for most of your posts, even the public ones, you will still only get “Unsupported get request”, which just means you are not allowed to read that object.

F.e., I have a public post where shared a video post from another page on my timeline, the `type` is `video` and `status_type` is `shared_story`, but neither `user_status` nor `user_videos` allow me to read this post – only when I grant `read_stream` again, my app can read that post. Same with another public post of  type `status` and status_type `mobile_status_update` – readable with `read_stream`, not with any of the `user_*` permissions.

In short: What you want to achieve is not possible any more with API v2 and the restriction that `read_stream` will only be granted to apps on platforms where no official FB client exists.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm going to go ahead and send you the bounty because it's expiring otherwise. So I actually think our app was grandfathered in on read_stream, it seems to have it at least for now. Do you know if that should that let me see all posts, or just my friends' posts, or just my own?

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/ only posts by people that have granted your app `read_stream` will be visible to your app when requesting a user’s feed (which would be the user’s own posts, and posts made by others on the user’s timeline). And after April 30, 2015 your app will not be able any more to ask people for any permission (besides the ones for user profile, friends and email) without your app undergoing review by FB first – and `read_stream` will not be granted to any app on a platform for which an official FB client exists.

Comment: yup, this is basically the same conclusion we came to in https://github.com/snarfed/activitystreams-unofficial/issues/26 . sigh. :(

Answer (score 0):

A one proposition is to make api calls to write facebook posts since those return valid post_id that you could use

Second,
When you try https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=525575504%2Fposts&version=v2.0&

You can see that his posts ID's are not starting with his `public id` as you wrote 525575504_*

but they still put unsupported get request

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/256884317673197/?method=GET&path=10152853212485505_351575675029953&version=v2.0

Third since above doesnt work are those posts public for sure?